# How to use code in firefox console and get information about fired event in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, firebug, extjs4.1

I am working in extjs4. Here I want to stuck at a point where I want to get information of event which is fired on a component of extjs4.i am using this link but I am not succeed.

http://loianegroner.com/2009/11/ext-js-which-events-are-fired-by-a-component/

i am using this code in firefox firebug command line...but not get any event when particular action get fired on a component.I dont know how to use it.Please give me some guideline...

Here is the code I am going to use it in firebug console command

```
Ext.util.Observable.capture(Ext.getCmp('loginId'), console.info);
```

I dont know how to use it and get succeed..please give me some advise..

here Is the screen shot of firebug how I am using.
[image: firebug console]
Please tell me is it correct or wrong.

Please tell me how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ext much...

But from what I can see, you cannot see what console.info logs simply because you filter the logs on Cookies.

[image: "Cookies" filter selected]

To see what logs console.info, I recommend you to select the "All" filter as below, which is the option by default:

[image: "All" filter selected]